# any available cross-platform LDAP client library?

Tags: c++, c, ldap

I wonder if there any available library which hides the OS-dependent LDAP client implementation details, like the idea for JDBC? and the library provides basic CRUD functionality also along with unified SSL API like what has been done in wldap32 in Windows.

Really appreciate!

Comment: i wanna have a cross-platform LDAP client which has basic CRUD functionality and with SSL enable option. any recommendation? thanks

Comment: @TadeuszA.Kadłubowski He wrote he wants a cross-platform library.

Comment: There's the Mozilla LDAP SDK, which is cross platform.